# How to properly setup flow to work with react-apollo?

Tags: graphql, flowtype, react-apollo

I know that some initial flow typing were [merged](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/pull/1688) in apollo-client.

- How can I use it?
- Should I declare my own lib definitions? (I use flow-typed currently).
- Could you please share an example of such definitions (particularly for react-apollo)?

For example, If I have such code:

```
// @flow
import { ApolloClient, createNetworkInterface } from 'react-apollo';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';

let apolloClient = null;

// Polyfill fetch() on the server (used by apollo-client)
if (!process.browser) {
  global.fetch = fetch;
}

function create() {
  return new ApolloClient({
    ssrMode: !process.browser, // Disables forceFetch on the server (so queries are only run once)
    networkInterface: createNetworkInterface({
      uri: 'https://api.graph.cool/simple/v1/cixmkt2ul01q00122mksg82pn', // Server URL (must be absolute)
      opts: {
        // Additional fetch() options like `credentials` or `headers`
        credentials: 'same-origin',
      },
    }),
  });
}
```

and on the other side in my lib def I have:

```
declare module 'react-apollo' {
  declare module.exports: any;
}
```

what should I type here(examples would be helpful) to have type checking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from [this](https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/a-stronger-typed-react-apollo-c43bd52be0d8) detailed article.

Answer (score 0):

For others trying to get Flow working with React Apollo:

> Flow is no longer supported with React Apollo.

See this [comment on GitHub](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/1510#issuecomment-422318981).